# Grunt helper prompt is not working

Tags: javascript, command-prompt, gruntjs

I'm writing a new plugin for grunt that are using some questions to solve some issues with translation. I wrote the plugin using `grunt.registerMultiTask();` And I call that tasks using  `grunt translate`. But at some part of the code I have a prompt for solving translation migration problems.

The code is:

```
grunt.helper('prompt', {}, [
  // Prompt for these values.
  grunt.helper('prompt_for', 'name')
], function(err, props) {
  // All done!
  done();
});
```

I wonder why it disregards the prompt in the command line. It just output the question and not waiting for an answer.

[image]

Comment: Did you call `var done = this.async();` in your task before calling `grunt.helper` to tell grunt that this task is asynchronous?